# SQl Delete from more than one table

Tags: sql, join

Say, I have two tables Courses and faculty_courses - each has a primary key course_ID that is varchar(50) not null.

I am trying to delete a row from the Courses table - so assume have to delete that row from both tables since they are linked by a relationship.

I wrote this - doesn't work - says  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'JOIN'

DELETE
FROM Courses JOIN faculty_courses ON Courses.course_ID = faculty_courses.course_ID
WHERE faculty_courses.course_ID = 'ITM731'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

You have to issue two statements.

```
DELETE Courses where course_ID = 'ITM731'
DELETE faculty_courses WHERE course_ID = 'ITM731'
```

Or, as mentioned here, use a delete cascade.

Comment: I typically recommend this instead of cascading deletes. This is a lot more visible as what the intention is.

Answer (score 2):

What you want can be handled by having [ON DELETE CASCADE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqls.doc/sqls118.htm) links between the tables.
Provided that your RDBMS allows for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [FK reference with CASCADE Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188066(SQL.90).aspx)

## Edit

I recommend that you use the approach from Ocedecio of explicitly deleting from the two tables as opposed to cascading. It makes your intention so much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

`DELETE` only delete record from one table - the JOIN syntax is useful only for selecting the correct rows on that table, for example, on table with an 1:n relationship (not what you have here) and you want to delete all the records from the "n" table that pertain to a selectable record on the "1" table, then you'd do `DELETE FROM ntable INNER JOIN reftable ON ntable.ref = reftable.ref WHERE reftable.column = 'whatyouneedtolookup'`.

Now as I said, this does not pertain to your current situation, in which you simply need to issue two `DELETE` statements - one for each table, on the same key.

That being said, it sounds like you have a 1:1 reference between the table which strikes me as odd - normally with that kind of reference, the trivial normalization would be to merge the tables into a single table with the columns from both tables.

Comment: 1:1 relationships can be valid in the case of subtyping an entity. In this case though I think he probably misspoke about the PK being the one column in both tables. Maybe faculty_courses is a composite key including the course_id?

Answer (score -2):

```
alter table tablename drop column columnname
```

Comment: OP wants to delete row. Not a column